# How many sets of two tiles can be selected from the bag, if we insist that the two chosen tiles contain different letters?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Scrabble Tiles:

[image]

Note that there are some repeated tiles. For example, the two S tiles are identical. For this question, we place all of the above tiles into a bag and then draw 2 tiles out of the bag.

How many **sets** of two tiles can be selected from the bag, if we insist that the two chosen tiles contain **different letters**?

---

***My Methods***

I know that one way of doing this question is to carefully put 2 different tiles together and do it for every tile and count the sets, but that is frankly very time consuming and not an effective way of doing this.

Another way I tried to do this is that I used combinations.

*Number of ways to choose two tiles:* ${}_{12} \mathrm{ C }_{2} = 66$

Then, $66 -$ (the number of ways that I can choose two identical tiles)

But this method will not give me the number of sets.

---

Can anyone help me in solving this question, I'm kinda confused on how to proceed with this question.

Comment: You get the number by putting in the bag one letter of each kind, so just one “o’ and so on

Comment: Yeah sorry, its a typo im going to edit it now

Comment: What do the subscripts signify, eg what does $C_3$ mean ?

Comment: @trueblueanil  The subscripts signify the number of points associated with the letter.  In Scrabble, you try to form words with the letters you have.  The number of points associated with the letters in the word is your score for that word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How would you get a two-element subset? You draw one tile from the bag and then another one; if it is the same as the first tile, discard it and draw another one; repeat until you get a different one.

You'd obtain the same if you discard repeated tiles from the beginning.

Since the distinct letters are eight

C O M P <s>O</s> S I T <s>I</s> <s>O</s> N <s>S</s>

you get …

Comment: So I did something like this: {CO,CM,CP,CS,CI,CT,CN,OM,OP,OS......} then I count them. Is that correct?

Comment: @BryanHii Use the binomial coefficients…